# nginx host default for IP

Tags: nginx

I have the following default configuration file in nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;

root /home/d/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;
```

Recently I added a file to host a specific domain, like:

```
server {
listen   80;
root /home/d/sites/dom
index index.html index.htm;

server_name dom.co www.dom.co;
```

After adding this, when loading the public server IP would be routed to this domain configuration folder, /home/d/sites/dom

How can the IP be directed to the default root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `listen 80 default;` for requests without `Host` header (if none set - the first one is used)

For requests with unrecognized host - special `server_name _;` matches

Comment: Good example here:https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Answer (score 0):

To add to Vasfed's answer, my block are:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/**yourdomain**

```
server {
listen   80;

root /www/sites/**yourdomain**;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name **yourdomain**.com www.**yourdomain**.com;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name _;
}
```

- These two files need to by sym-linked to sites-enabled.